# How to generate odata.nextlink in odata based C# web api with server side pagination

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, odata

I'm looking for a dotnet core web API with OData implementation with server-side pagination.

I have a ProductController with a dbcontext to get the data, inorder to improve the performance, choose the server-side pagination approach i.e., using skipToken.

I have tried implementing Custom SkipTokenHandler, but we dont have necessary parameters in `GenerateNextLink` method to perform custom pagination calculation

i.e., get total record count in that table and use the page size to calculate the number of pages and generate custom skiptoken using it

```
public class CustomODataSkipTokenHandler : DefaultSkipTokenHandler
{
    public override IQueryable<T> ApplyTo<T>(IQueryable<T> query, SkipTokenQueryOption skipTokenQueryOption, ODataQuerySettings querySettings, ODataQueryOptions queryOptions)
    {
        return query;
    }

    public override IQueryable ApplyTo(IQueryable query, SkipTokenQueryOption skipTokenQueryOption, ODataQuerySettings querySettings, ODataQueryOptions queryOptions)
    {
        return query;
    }

    public override Uri GenerateNextPageLink(Uri baseUri, int pageSize, object instance, ODataSerializerContext context)
    {
        var queryOptions = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(baseUri.Query);
        string skipToken = queryOptions.Get("$skiptoken");
        
        // need total record count to calculate the number of pages and all pagination till last
        int pageNumber = 1;
        SkipToken token = new SkipToken(pageNumber);
        queryOptions.Set("$skiptoken", token.ToString());

        string encodedQuery = queryOptions.ToString();
        UriBuilder builder = new UriBuilder(baseUri);
        builder.Query = encodedQuery;
        return builder.Uri;
    }
}
```

**Updates:**

The default odata framework implementation uses `ID` property for pagination (refer below screenshot), but incase if the ID column does not have a sequential value then this way of pagination will lead to returning same result repetitively, so do we have any other way of implementing our own custom pagenation handler which give option to perform skip and top with user defined or default sorting.

[image]

Custom next page link generator works using `PageResult` but now the `$select` query is not working and throwing self reference error

`Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Self referencing loop detected for property 'DeclaringType' with type 'Microsoft.OData.Edm.EdmEntityType'. Path 'TypedProperty.SchemaElements[0].DeclaredKey[0]'`

Comment: Could you please describe a bit more what exact issue you are getting while setting `skiptoken` aren't it working as expected? [`Have you checked this official document`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/odata/webapi/skiptoken-for-server-side-paging)?

Comment: Take a look at this section of a doc on server-side paging https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/odata/webapi-8/fundamentals/server-driven-paging#improving-paging-with-skiptoken

Comment: In addition, here's a tutorial on how you can create a custom skip token handler https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/odata/webapi-8/tutorials/custom-skiptokenhandler?tabs=net60%2Cvisual-studio

Comment: the out of the box skip token uses "ID" column to generate the skiptoken and even the documentation of custom skip token handler uses same internally. I'm looking for custom skip token generator which can perform skip and top based on page size and order by user defined property.